# How can I work around Visual Studio 2012 not supporting explicit conversion operators?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, type-conversion

Here's a contrived, off-the-cuff example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo
{
    int num;

public:
    foo() : num(0) {}
    foo(int i) : num(i) {}

    explicit operator int() const { return num; }
    foo operator+(const foo& rhs) const { return foo(num + rhs.num); }
    foo& operator=(const foo& rhs) : num(rhs.num) { return *this; };

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o) { o << num; return o; }
};

void main()
{
    foo bar = 4; // Works fine

    cout << bar + 3; // Error C2071.  Will be Error C2666 if 'explicit' is removed
    // cout << (int) bar + 3; // If I get rid of 'explicit' above, the above
                              //   line must be switched with this to compile
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to add or assign an `int` to a `foo` without explicit conversion of the `foo` instance.

My first code attempt wouldn't compile, because (if I understand this correctly) when I didn't have `explicit` specified on the conversion operator, `bar + 3` counted as an operator overload -- `bar` and 3 could both be `foo` or `int`, so VS didn't know whether to run (arithmetic, arithmetic) or (`foo`, `foo`) on them.

On my second code attempt (above), I added `explicit` to the conversion operator, so that `bar` had to be a `foo` in that situation, meaning there's no overload.

The problem is that [Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support explicit conversion operators](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx).  It gives me "Error C2071: illegal storage class" when I try to use them.

So here's my question: is it possible to get the behavior I'm desiring?  Again - I want to be able to add or assign an `int` to a `foo` through `foo::operator+` or `foo::operator=`, without using explicit conversion on the instance of `foo`.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't understand the issue(s). One thing, that _may_ be relevant is: you should keep in mind, that `foo(int i) { num = i; }` actually allows "implicit conversion" from `int` to `foo`, as the constructor takes one argument and is not declared as `explicit`. No idea if this helps, but I really didn't understand the different tests and what exactly failed/fails.

Comment: Right - I have that copy constructor there to allow implicit conversion from `int` to `foo` so that I can add or assign `int`s straight to `foo`.  The problem is that if I just type the expression `bar + 4`, where `bar` is an instance of `foo`, the compiler doesn't know whether to convert 4 to `foo` or whether to convert `bar` to `int` (since I have a conversion operator).  I tried making the conversion operator explicit, but Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support this, so I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: I see. Can't you try defining a `operator+`, taking `int` as argument? Not sure if this will be fine (or ambiguous again), but worth trying, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
class foo
{
    int num;

public:
    foo() : num(0) {}
    /*explicit*/ foo(int i) { num = i; }

    /*explicit*/ operator int() const { return num; }
    foo& operator=(const foo& rhs) { num = rhs.num; return *this; };

    friend foo operator+(const foo& lhs, const foo& rhs) { return foo(lhs.num + rhs.num); }
    friend foo operator+(int lhs, const foo& rhs) { return foo(lhs + rhs.num); }
    friend foo operator+(const foo& lhs, int rhs) { return foo(lhs.num + rhs); }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const foo& rhs) { o << rhs.num; return o; }
};
```

So, there is no conversion (there is an exact match).

Answer (score 1):

Define `operator+=` as a member function and `operator+` as a friend function:

```
class foo
{
    foo& operator+=(const foo& obj);
    friend foo operator+(const foo& obj1,const foo& obj2);
};

foo& f::operator+=(const foo& obj)
{
    return *this=*this+obj;
}

friend foo operator+(const foo& obj1,const foo& obj2)
{
    return foo(obj1.num+obj2.num)
}
```

BTW, you'd also need to implement 'operator<<' for printing...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I needed `operator<<`.  I added it above.  I'm trying out `friend`, and I'll let you know how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: NP... I believe it should allow you to do `cout<<bar+3` as well as `cout<<3+bar` as well as `cout<<bar1+bar2`, and you can get rid of the `int` casting operator altogether. In fact, the compiler might shout "ambiguous function call" if you keep all the operators above together with `operator int()`.

Comment: Hmm....well, that mostly works, but I would also like to have the option to say `cout << (int) bar`.  I guess it's not possible to have both that **and** the ability to say `cout << bar + 3`...

Comment: I did not really compile or run any of the code fixes suggested above. Did you try to leave the `int` casting operator as is? I am not sure that the compiler will then shout "ambiguous" for `cout<<bar+3` or `count<<3+bar` (I was just guessing that it might)...

Comment: In general, binary operators such as `operator+` should be declared as global functions rather than member functions, for the reason mentioned above. As to `operator<<`, if you're not planning to use it for logical operations within your class (such as 'shift-left' for example), then you might as well use it for printing. But sometimes this is not the case (for example, if you design a class for storing very large integers, and you want to provide 'shift' operators). I usually go for `printf` rather than `cout` because of this specific reason.

Comment: P.S.: if the answer worked for you, then you can mark it useful and/or correct...